# Is there a "Before" Navigated event?

Tags: .net, wpf, navigation, navigationservice

Im using WPF with Navigation Service. I need to catch a situation before the next page is navigated. Is thera any event "before" next page is navigated?

```
Navigate("MyPage1.xaml")
Navigate("MyPage2.xaml")'now, I need a event which shows me : FromPage("MyPage1.xaml") before navigating to "MyPage2.xaml".
```

code sample

```
Private Sub Window_Loaded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    Application.NavigationService = Me.ContentFrame.NavigationService
End Sub

Class Application
    ' Application-level events, such as Startup, Exit, and DispatcherUnhandledException
    ' can be handled in this file.
    Public Shared NavigationService As NavigationService
End Class



Private Sub ContentFrame_Navigated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs) Handles ContentFrame.Navigated
    If Application.cLang Is Nothing Then Call InitializeLanguage()
    'The following Welcome page is never visible because e.Uri is always the NEXT page
    If e.Uri IsNot Nothing AndAlso (e.Uri.ToString.Contains("Pages/PageWelcome.xaml")) Then
        Call UpdateLanguageCombobox()
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub ContentFrame_Navigating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigatingCancelEventArgs) Handles ContentFrame.Navigating
    Dim Uri As Uri = CType(sender, Frame).Source
    If Application.cLang Is Nothing Then Call InitializeLanguage()
    'The following Welcome page is never visible because e.Uri is always the NEXT page
    If e.Uri IsNot Nothing AndAlso (e.Uri.ToString.Contains("Pages/PageWelcome.xaml")) Then
        'Call UpdateLanguageCombobox()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Try the [Navigating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow.navigating.aspx) event. It is raised when a navigation is requested. More information on NavigationServices events is found in the "Remarks" section of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615518.aspx.

Comment: Hi Ben. The problem is, that "Navigating" also contains only the next and not the current page. ohh damn, I was on the line... I can just call `?CType(sender, Frame).Source.ToString` in this case. thanks for your advice.

Comment: Ok, tried. Sorry but the problem is, that in any case the Uri always contains the url which needs to be loaded. I cannot see the current or last uri. `?CType(sender, Frame).Source.ToString` does not work.

Comment: Try casting sender to the type NavigationWindow and then accessing the CurrentSource property.

Comment: Hi Ben. One post before and another post before I wrote, that I did this but it does only support "next" uri not current. Ask me why? I don't know. But it is unusable. casting of frame does not work. Perhaps "NavigationWindow" could be something else? But I only have one Frame control for navigation. I navigate by using `Frame.Source = Uri` perhaps that's wrong?

Comment: Would you please provide a code sample of how you are setting up/registering your event handler?

Comment: I allow to post code sample in the question box. Because of better formatting. one second...

Comment: Try catching the Navigating event raised by *NavigationService*.

Comment: Navigation Service of Application holds the same result like the Frame Navigation service. I fixed this now by using my own variable to remember last visited page. Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight, there is an event "OnNavigatedFom" that occurs before navigating to that page.. Hope it might be the same for WPF as well..

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e) {
    base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
}
```